# How to make a multicast IPTV video stream accessible through WiFi, when it's only accessible through wired connection

Tags: wireless-networking, video, multicast, iptv

So thanks to my service provider I'm able to watch some TV channels through the computer, using software (VLC, ffplay, MPlayer, etc) that is capable of playing multicast UDP streams. My problem is that the playback of these channels is only possible via wired connection. I was wondering what might be my options to make these channels also accessible through WiFi?

I guess one way is to restream it, so that if someone wants to watch the channel, I'd have to turn on the desktop computer and start restreaming it to the network. But I don't see it as a very good option. Are there any other options?

//
Ok, so I was asked to add additional details about my router. It's Thomson's 789vn with software version of 8.C.D.5. For a temporary solution, I am just restreaming the stream if someone wants to watch it through a WiFi-device (smartphone, tablet, laptop, etc). The problem is, that for this I have to have at least one computer powered on, that has a wired connection. And then on this computer which has a wired connection, I'd use the command:

```
vlc --intf dummy udp://@239.3.1.2:1234 :sout=#http{mux=ts,dst=:8080/} :sout-all :sout-keep
```

And then the WiFi-devices are able to watch the stream by opening the network stream in VLC corresponding to the IP, for example `http://192.168.1.20:8080`.
But what if my desktop PC is turned off and I'm so far from it to turn it on. Or if it's turned on, how I could remotely start the "sharing" of the stream?

Comment: Please include more details (make and model) on your WiFi AP/router in your question.

Comment: Added some details and clarified.

Comment: Unfortunately multicasts are very expensive on Wi-Fi, making this a bad idea. Multicast packets on Wi-Fi must be sent at a low data rate so everyone can receive them. This wastes a lot of airtime (bandwidth). Multicasts are also buffered for short periods of time and sent all at once (DTIM interval), potentially causing jitter for real-time A/V streaming protocols. For best results, keep your clients close to the AP so you can set your multicast rate high, set your DTIM interval to 0, and disable power save mode on ALL client devices. I strongly advise against Wi-Fi multicast streaming.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can set up your WiFi connection so that you could watch the streams via WiFi.

It is best if you can set up a separate virtual access point (if your router supports creating Virtual Access Points). The reason for this is that enabling the streaming of UDP with IGMP floods your WiFi network reducing its efficiency as other wireless devices that don't want the stream  packets will receive them. By creating  this virtual access point only those who want to watch the Stream can connect to it.

First, tell me what type of router you are using.

Just go through these links to get an idea.

http://ddscentral.org/2010/10/iptv-and-vlans-problem-solved.html

Configuring your router can be quite confusing because there are several steps to follow before you can get the stream working via WiFi.

1. Create a virtual access point in the WLAN page of your router.
2. Enable IGMP protocol where you see it e.g. in the LAN page or where ever it is in your router.
3. Go to the Port Mapping page (a.k.a. VLAN functions) page of your router.
4. Know it's all up to you, find the interface/ group that your IPTV set up box is connected to.
5. Add the Virtual Access point interface (WLAN- VP0/ this should be your virtual access point interface, depends on your router ) to the group which has your IPTV box is connected to. This will forward your UDP packets to your Virtual WiFi interface.
6. Connect to your new access point using a laptop, etc. Sometimes UDP won't work on some Android devices as they don't support multicasting.  For that further configuration is needed.

That's it! Hope it works because it worked for me. All the best. Cheers Mate.

Comment: This is mostly correct, but multicast groups *are* implemented on WiFi. It’s just that the radio only has finite bandwidth. A separate SSID doesn’t solve this problem either. If someone wants to receive the stream, the data has to be transmitted.

Comment: Dear Twisty,  I  cannot steam the IPTV channels to android Tablet, but the streams work for all my other devices! I tried different  players as well! Should I use udpxy  on my router? Or how can I configure a proxy server. Thanks Chandula

Comment: This answer is fine as far as IGMP and VLAN considerations go, but doesn't really take Wi-Fi limitations into account or address Wi-Fi adjustments for multicast, like the multicast rate, DTIM interval, disabling power save, etc.